# Import image assets typescript react

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to import img when using typescript in my react project

```
import * as img from "./assets/webpack.png";
```

But I got the error TS2307: Cannot find module './assets/webpack.png'.

I search arround and find the solution saying that I have to add

```
declare module "*.png" {
  const value: any;
  export default value;
}
```

But I don't know where to add it.

I created a declarations.d.ts file at my root project and add it to the file but nothing happens. I still got the error

Could you show me how to add it. Thank you in advanced

Answer (score 0):

The solution is that you have to put declarations.d.ts in the asserts folder, not the root folder. I have to be in the same folder with your image files

Comment: This is not entirely true at all. Have you declared your typing roots in your `tsconfig` and `tslint` so your compiler knows where to look these files from?

Comment: Yes I do but it does not work. And it works when I put it in the same folder with my img file

Comment: This only means your `TypeScript` configuration -file is not correctly declared.

Comment: Do you have a sample project that has the correct configuration?

Comment: https://github.com/bumpah/react-context-i18n this is one of my personal projecta where typings lies with in root in there own folder